# Reading pointers in python from root

Tags: python, pointers, root-framework

I am not sure if this question is actually about pointers because I am not very sure what they are, but I have to read some .root file using python. Below is a screenshot of the file.

[image]

I managed to read the numbers but I can't read the vectors (or pointers - I am not sure what they are). I am new to root. Here is the reading part of the code where t1 is a TTree inside the file.

```
a.append(root.TChain("t1"))

for chain in a:
    chain.Add(input) 
entries =  a[0].GetEntries()
```

And this is the reading of some number variables (not the ones in the picture):

```
import pandas as pd
entries =  chain[0].GetEntries()

xp_pri = []
yp_pri = []
X_shower = []
Y_shower = []

for k in range(entries):
    for a in chain:
        a.LoadTree(k)
        a.GetEntry(k)

        xp_pri = xp_pri + [chain[0].xp_pri]
        yp_pri = yp_pri + [chain[0].yp_pri]
        X_shower = X_shower + [chain[0].X_shower/10**10]
        Y_shower = Y_shower + [chain[0].Y_shower/10**10]
```

So my question is how do I read the vectors, because if I use the same procedure: chain[0].xp_pri, the program stops working?

Comment: You should include a complete example (including any imports), otherwise it's very hard to get the context around your question.

Answer (score 1):

create

```
myvec = ROOT.std.vector('float')()
```

or

```
myvec = ROOT.std.vector('int')()
```

then:

```
chain.SetBranchAddress("the_branch_name",myvec)
```

after:

```
chain.GetEntry(some_entry_number)
```

*myvec* will contain the values for event number *some_entry_number*.

Your other option is to use [root_numpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/root_numpy/)  which is capable of retrieving vectors too.